# Quais as características e funcionalidades do Apache Struts?

Tags: struts2

Particularmente não conheço como é a estrutura e o funcionamento desse framework, mas pelo que tenho lido sobre o assunto, ele vem sendo muito utilizado no desenvolvimento Web.

Quais as características e funcionalidades do ***Apache Struts***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denis,

O Apache Struts, tanto o 1, como o 2, é sim, um framework muito utilizado na Indústria. Principalmente como Solução para sistemas que se beneficiem da arquitetura MVC.  Sem dúvida, você encontrará muitos projetos utilizando ele.

Na minha experiência tenho visto muitas aplicações sendo migradas para Spring MVC.
Portanto, posso te dizer que não há mais muitos projetos novos sendo construídos em Struts, pelo menos não nos meios onde estou. Eu também já trabalhei com Struts 1, e posso afirmar que é inferior ao Spring MVC 3.0, pois o último oferece mais funcionalidades e melhor **separation of concerns** além de um melhor desacoplamento, pois no Struts um é necessário herdar classes, como as ***ActionForms***

As principais vantagens que eu notei ao trabalhar com ele foram:

- Uma rica taglib para criação de *.JSPs*. Haviam muitas tags auto-explicativas que eu pude usar com facilidade, para pelo menos *naquela época* gerar conteúdo HTML dinâmico
- Renderizar *POJOs*, mapeando-os diretamente a propriedades descritas em tags dos JSPs, o problema é que eu tinha que escrever classes *Adapters* pois ele só renderizava *FormBeans*(classes herdadas de componentes do Struts).
- Me afastou da programação direta com *Servlets*(Servlet API), pois ele já abstraia essa camada.
- Me permitiou associar páginas com URLs, e essas URLs com Actions, que tem o papel de ***Controller*** no Struts( o **C** do **MVC**)

> Quais as características e funcionalidades do Apache Struts?

***Funcionalidades Core***

- Arquitetura da estrutura conectável que permite que os ciclos de vida
  de solicitação possam ser personalizados para cada Action.
- Estrutura de validação flexível que permite que regras de validação
  possam ser desacopladas do código da Action.
- Abordagem hierárquica à internacionalização que simplifica a
  localização de aplicativos.
- Conversão de tipo automática que mapeia de forma transparente os
  valores de HTTP para objetos de dados Java nativos, resolvendo um dos
  esforços mais tediosos ao criar aplicações web.
- Motor de injeção de dependência integrado que gerencia o ciclo de
  vida e dependências dos componentes.
- Arquivos de configuração modular que usam pacotes e namespaces para
  simplificar o gerenciamento de grandes projetos com centenas de
  Actions.
- Anotações Java 5 disponíveis(programação declarativa)

Aqui há uma comparação entre a versão 1 e 2:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/comparing-struts-1-and-2.html